# C# - How to avoid repeated code of the Sql Connection to all members method

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

In my C# WinForm Application, I had three member of button which designed as **SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE**. Each button read same database table when clicked. When i ready to make the code, I wont like to repeat the code of sql connection and based code such as SqlAdapter, SqlCommand etc.. in all members methods which i given above. So the question is how should avoid that repeated code because its not best coding style.

```
button_Select_Click(...)
{
    //sql releated code
    //get data from database and display in some_display_tool_1
}
button_Insert_Click(...)
{
    //sql releated code
    //get data from database and display in some_display_tool_1
}
button_Update_Click(...)
{
   //sql releated code
   //get data from database and display in some_display_tool_1
}
```

These are present Pseudocode. I would not want whole code from yours. So Please provide me a better idea in the way of PseudoCode. Sorry, please understand my english.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Show us the method which contains such code. Also give comments on line/s of code which you want to make generic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the Repository Pattern and Entity Framework?